# How do I lock the Plot Area's size so it doesn't resize when I resize the Chart Area? (Excel/Office 365)

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, label

I have two pie charts side by side and I want them to be the same size.

However, in pie chart #2, I need to move the Data Labels away from the pie chart which means resizing the Chart Area.

The trouble is, when I resize the Chart Area, the Plot Area (containing the pie chart) also gets resized. I don't want this to happen. I need to lock the size of the Plot Area so it doesn't get resized when I resize the Chart Area.

Is this possible? If so, please can you let me know how?

I am using Excel in Office 365.

[image: screenshot of chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to create a bigger pie chart that would encapsulate the bigger data labels and used that as the base size for both charts. Well, that was my initial solution, in the end I settled for XX% inside the segments and used legends underneath for the descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

> > However, in pie chart #2, I need to move the Data Labels away from the pie chart which means resizing the Chart Area.

I think moving the Date Labels away does not means resizing the Chart Area.

> > The trouble is, when I resize the Chart Area, the Plot Area (containing the pie chart) also gets resized. I don't want this to happen. I need to lock the size of the Plot Area so it doesn't get resized when I resize the Chart Area.

Yes, when resizing the Chart Area, the Plot Area also gets resized. But you can size Plot Area again after resizing the Chart Area.

[image]