# Is it possible to shrink the plot box while keeping chart area in charts in Excel 365 online?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

Is it possible to shrink the plot box while keeping chart area in charts in Excel 365 online? In Excel 2016+ for Windows, a plot has a box that lies within the chart area. This box can be resized, allowing additional elements (e.g., text boxes) to be placed entirely outside the plot box. This is important: the text is part of the chart but need to overlap the plot box. In Excel 365 online, the plot box seems bound to the chart area (or, perhaps there is not separate chart area?). Is there no way to achieve the outcome of a text box *inside* the chart area but *outside* the plot box in the online version?

Btw, an answer to [How do I lock the Plot Area's size so it doesn't resize when I resize the Chart Area? (Excel/Office 365)](https://superuser.com/questions/1463921/how-do-i-lock-the-plot-areas-size-so-it-doesnt-resize-when-i-resize-the-chart) seems to suggest it is possible, but the illustration seems to be using the downloaded Office app and not the online version.

Comment: Did you try the lock feature?

Comment: @Lee I don't see how that helps. Btw, in the online version, the format menu does not include "Format Chart Area".